# Accidentally creating two PHP loops

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have been working on resolving this problem for two days. I'm sure it's a simple fix but I am fairly new to PHP. I need to generate three items using a loop that cycles through an array. I also need to append a number to an ID AND I need to apply a selected class based on parameters identified elsewhere.

Another user was kind enough to help me along this far and I've almost accomplished what I need. The problem is I have two loops that create more instances than I need and I'm not sure how to keep my counter while getting rid of the loop.

What I have so far:

```
<?php 
$tabs = array('first_tab_page', 'second_tab_page', 'third_tab_page');
$pages = array();
foreach ($tabs as $tab){
    $pageid = opt($tab);
    $post = get_post($pageid);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
    $icon = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
    $pages[] = array('pageid' => $pageid, 'post' => $post, 'content' => $content, 'icon' => $icon);
}

$tab_position = opt('tab_position');
if ($tab_position == '' || count($tab_position) != 3) {
    $tab_position = array(0, 1, 2);
}

for($i=0; $i < count($tab_position); $i++){
    $selected = '';
    if (opt('default_selected_tab') == $tab_position[$i]){
        $selected = 'class="selected"';
    }

    foreach ($pages as $page){
?>
<a <?php echo $selected; ?> href="#tab<?php echo $tab_position[$i];?>">
<?php echo $page['content']; ?>
</a>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

That creates this:

```
<a class="selected" href="#tab0">
    <p>1st Content</p>
</a>
<a class="selected" href="#tab0">
    <p>2nd Content</p>
</a>
<a class="selected" href="#tab0">
    <p>3rd Content</p>
</a>
<a href="#tab1">
    <p>1st Content</p>
</a>
<a href="#tab1">
    <p>2nd Content</p>
</a>
<a href="#tab1">
    <p>3rd Content</p>
</a>
<a href="#tab2">
    <p>1st Content</p>
</a>
<a href="#tab2">
    <p>2nd Content</p>
</a>
<a href="#tab2">
    <p>3rd Content</p>
</a>
```

**I need this:**

```
<a class="selected" href="#tab0">
    <p>1st Content</p>
</a>
<a href="#tab1">
    <p>2nd Content</p>
</a>
<a href="#tab2">
    <p>3rd Content</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Come up with a solution that doesn't use loops. Get it working. And then figure out how to roll it into a loop.

Comment: They both do the job they are intended to do individually. But I need to find a solution that lets me cycle through the $tabs array AND appends the $tab_position array number as well as adds the selected class.

Comment: Do the pages correlate exactly to tabs? If so, why don't you just structure your array that way?

Comment: That might be possible but I'd still have to figure out how to apply the selected class.

Comment: You know what, I don't really need the ability to set the class selected dynamically. I'm just going to add in <? if ($i === 0): ?> class="selected" <? endif; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to user [bansi](/users/2522554/bansi).

```
<?php 
    $tabs = array('first_tab_page', 'second_tab_page', 'third_tab_page');
    $pages = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($tabs as $tab){
        $pageid = opt($tab);
        $post = get_post($pageid);
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
        $icon = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
        //Store everything to $pages array
        $selected = '';
        if (opt('default_selected_tab') == $i){
            $selected = 'class="selected"';
        }
        $pages[] = array('pageid' => $pageid, 'post' => $post, 'content' => $content, 'icon', $icon, 'selected' => $selected, 'tab_position' => $i);
        $i++;
    }

foreach ($pages as $page){
?>

<a <?php echo $page['selected']; ?> href="#tab<?php echo $page['tab_position'];?>">
<?php echo $page['content']; //echo the content of page ?>
</a>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code it may help you ,

```
  <?php 
    $tabs = array('first_tab_page', 'second_tab_page', 'third_tab_page');
    $pages = array();
    foreach ($tabs as $tab){
        $pageid = opt($tab);
        $post = get_post($pageid);
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
        $icon = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
        $pages[] = array('pageid' => $pageid, 'post' => $post, 'content' => $content, 'icon' => $icon);
    }
    $tab_position = opt('tab_position');
                if ($tab_position == '' || count($tab_position) != 3) {
                    $tab_position = array(0, 1, 2);
                }

                for($i=0; $i < count($tab_position); $i++)
                {
                    $selected = '';
                    if (opt('default_selected_tab') == $tab_position[$i]){
                        $selected = 'class="selected"';
                    }

}
foreach ($pages as $page){
 ?>

 <a <?php echo $selected; ?> href="#tab<?php echo $tab_position[$i];?>">
 <?php echo $page['content']; ?>
 </a>

 <?php }

 ?>
```

Comment: Nope :( It get's rid of everything under the $tab_position was intended to do (add the array number and selected class).